# ZeroMQ - Number of Threads

Tags: c++, zeromq

**Q1:** How many threads are created when using ZeroMQ?

According to ( output from **`$ ps -o nlwp <pid>`** ) the following program creates 3 threads.

**Q2:** Why?

**Q3:** Shouldn't this be just 2 ( one for main, one for I/O-thread, given `num_zmq_io_threads == 1` )?

**Q4:** Is this documented anywhere?

```
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    const int num_zmq_io_threads = 1;        
    zmq::context_t context( num_zmq_io_threads );

    zmq::socket_t socket1( context, ZMQ_PUB );
    socket1.bind( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" );

    for(;;)
    {
        // spin
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you take out the socket call?

Comment: You can read the source to see how many threads are created and for what use.

Comment: If the socket call is removed, no threads are created.

Answer (score 1):

ZeroMQ will create a reaper thread to handle socket shutdown, in addition to the number of I/O-threads called for. If you ask for zero I/O-threads, possible when using only intra-processess messages, there will still be a reaper thread. This is why you appear to get one more thread than asked for.

The reason you see no threads when the socket is not created is because ZeroMQ doesn't create the threads on **`context`** creation; they are created later.  This is more apparent with the ZeroMQ C API, where there are no options when creating the context with [**`zmq_ctx_new()`**](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-ctx-new), and then options like number and priority of I/O-threads must be specified after the context is created with  [**`zmq_ctx_set()`**](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-ctx-set).

Creating the socket triggers ZMQ to create the threads. I don't know where it's documented when exactly ZMQ will create threads. I.e., does it always create all threads when the first socket is created on a `context` or  is it more complex than that? For instance, does it depend on when the socket created has some I/O-operation for a thread to perform?